Access private (#) member function from callback
I'm trying to pass a private member function to a callback. The issue is that the callback then can't access the function and throws the error "Cannot read private member from an object whose class did not declare it"
class MyClass {

  async foo(msg: string) {
    const cb = async (bar: string) => { return await this.#personalFoo(msg, bar) };
    return await otherFunction(cb);
  }

  async #personalFoo(msg: string, bar: string) {
    // Do some async stuff with msg and bar
  }

}

export async function otherFunction<T>(callback: (bar: string) => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
  const bar = "whatever";
  return await callback(bar);
}

I then call foo from another class. The actual situation is hard to reproduce here, since I'm working with NestJS, which takes care of the dependency injections. MyClass is a service, and I call foo from a controller.
@Injectable()
class MyController {
  constructor(@Inject(MyClass.name) private readonly myClass: MyClass) {}

  @Post()
  async fooEndpoint() {
    return await this.myClass.foo();
  }
}

What I've tried so far
I've had a deep look at this question and it's answers, especially this one. I tried using the self approach, I tried bind(this) with a regular function, a combination of self and regular function, and the arrow function above. The results are always the same.
self
class MyClass {

  async foo(msg: string) {
    const self = this;
    const cb = async (bar: string) => { return await self.#personalFoo(msg, bar) };
    return await otherFunction(cb);
  }

  async #personalFoo(msg: string, bar: string) {
    // Do some async stuff with msg and bar
  }

}

bind(this)
class MyClass {

  async foo(msg: string) {
    const cb = async function (bar: string) {
      return await this.#personalFoo(msg, bar);
    }.bind(this);
    return await otherFunction(cb);
  }

  async #personalFoo(msg: string, bar: string) {
    // Do some async stuff with msg and bar
  }

}

Using private instead of # works
When using private instead of # (without any further changes to the code), it works fine. I understand the difference between private and # is runtime access restriction, which I assume is the issue here. But I don't quite understand why, since I'm binding the instance of MyClass, which should have access to it's members even at runtime.
private -> this works
class MyClass {

  async foo(msg: string) {
    const cb = async (bar: string) => { return await this.personalFoo(msg, bar) };
    return await otherFunction(cb);
  }

  private async personalFoo(msg: string, bar: string) {
    // Do some async stuff with msg and bar
  }

}


Your problem isn't with accessing the private member, it's with making sure that this is correct in the callback.

I don't think so, because I have tried different approaches that work fine with the same setup for this. If I'm wrong, I would be thankful for advice on where exactly the issue is.

"The issue is that the callback then can't access the function and throws an error." - which error? And how are you calling foo? Please post a complete [mcve].

"Cannot read private member from an object whose class did not declare it" - that problem appears to be unrelated to the callback. You're using the arrow function correctly, but apparently you are not calling .foo() on an instance of MyClass(). It wouldn't work if you were to call this.#personalFoo(msg, 'whatever') from directly within foo either.

I have added a little more context. The actual function call to .foo() happens from another class, which has access to a reference to an instance of MyClass

Hm, everything looks fine. I cannot reproduce the issue. Are you using any weird transpiler?

Oh wow, thanks for putting in that effort for an initially rather poorly formulated question. I am using NestJS with target set to 'ES2021' in tsconfig. Could that be the issue? At least now I know that in theory it should work.

Hm, is nestjs somehow wrapping or proxying the instance? That could explain the problem (and why normal property access still works). Have you tried stepping through using a debugger?

Yes, I have tried the debugger, I actually do that by default with new code. I really have no clue, and I didn't expect this to be such an issue. I have settled with private, it's a better tradeoff. Thanks a lot for your support!

Have you tried using exactly the code you posted? because I can see the error thrown only when using a function instead of an arrow function, and this could make sense because of how different ordinary function are from arrow ones.
So the following code throws the error
  async foo(msg: string) {
    const cb = async function (bar: string) { return await this.#personalFoo(msg, bar) };
    return await otherFunction(cb);
  }

while the following doesn't
  async foo(msg: string) {
    const cb = async (bar: string) => { return await this.#personalFoo(msg, bar) };
    return await otherFunction(cb);
  }


Thanks. I have tried both ways, they both unfortunately don't work. I have also tried binding this to the regular function, which also didn't work. Since it seems this should actually work, I'm assuming it has something to do with the settings in my NestJS project.

I have marked this as the accepted answer (even though the issue still persists), since I believe that the actual issue is hidden somewhere deeper in the project and way out of scope of this question.
